# Java 9 Eclipse does not include Maven dependencies

Tags: eclipse, maven

I downloaded the Spring Tool Suite which uses the latest Eclipse (4.7.1a) and imported the code from https://github.com/ConSol/java9-modules-maven-junit-example

This project compiles great from the command line, but in Eclipse, it refuses to take the Maven dependencies into account. On the classpath, I see the maven dependencies specified and everything looks fine, but I still see those errors:

[image: Eclipse classpath errors]

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The latest Eclipse is Oxygen.2 (4.7.2), but that shouldn't make any difference here. Did you try to right-click the project and choose _Maven > Update Project..._?

Comment: The "Error Log" is clear?

Comment: @Crigges The _Error Log_ view shows Eclipse errors that have been logged, not Java, Maven or other Eclipse project errors.

Comment: Have correctly configured Maven? Using the correct settings.xml file ?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I will check this evening. Just to be clear, running the project from the command line works! And updating the project does nothing. To me it seems like a bug, but maybe I am missing something!

Comment: no settings.xml is used plus no relative errors in the error log view. But I do see a note in preferences - maven - installations: "Embedded maven is used for resolving dependencies" and there is where it goes wrong because the maven dependencies are added (see screenshot) but when used to import in a class, the class is not found.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with Eclipse 4.7.3.   I tried it with Maven and without Maven.  I create a Java project without maven and I'm still getting the same problem.   There is an Eclipse problem specifying external libraries to the project.   It's strange because all this stuff worked fine before.

Comment: There is apperantly a problem in the JDT of eclipse. It should be fixed with version 4.8. Havent tested it yet